# What is the incentive for mortal beings to go on an epic adventure to gather resources for the gods?

Tags: medieval, gods

Set in the medieval period, the benevolent gods periodically post requests for brave mortals to go on an adventure of a lifetime. There are usually no rewards upon successful completion of the quest. There are no save points along the way where the adventurer may head back to town and restock or respawn. Fatalities for partaking such a quest are higher than those for contracting the Black Death. The gods do not have obligation to intervene in the people's business, and they can restart genesis if everybody is gone. People are just a pawn to them, but still there are men and women forming a line to sign up for the perilous vacation. What can be the incentive for them? Many of those adventurers do not worship the gods nor do they fear the gods.

Comment: These gods do not sound benevolent. They sound ambivalent at best.

Comment: seems like if they dont follow the god request they will get genesis, they may not fear god but they probably still care about their family, friend, etc so they try to not get genesis by following god order, like it or not. unless they know how to replace this god or a way to rebel without triggering genesis.

Comment: A fake promise of Heaven in the afterlife or to become a god themself can get the job done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Initiation rite to enter in a powerful group

Initiation rite and rite of passsage exists in many cultures and organization. Sometimes, it's just symbolic, such as the baptem for christians, but it can be way more brutal.

There are several examples, such as spartans, who were taken away from their family for militar training, and need to kill zelot without being discovered to validate their training, or gagns that make you commit a crime before you enter in the organization.

Your sect may have religious roots, without making all members zealous. However, in order to be accepted as a member, one need to achieve a quest given by the gods.

If this society is prestigious/powerful/rich/whatever, it can be a pretty powerful incentives, and promise a good career for all the ninth-born sons who have nothing to lose.

Answer (score 5):

There’s a lot of things people do without promise of a reward. Dangerous, arduous things.

Like fighting massive bushfires. Thousands of firefighters converged on Australia this year to fight a particularly awful bushfire season, most of them volunteers. None of them will get much more than a medal and recognition for a job well done (maybe a small stipend to compensate for the protracted deployment), but they went out anyway.

Why do they do it? Well, for some it’s their job. For others, it’s because it’s their homes in the line of fire - either immediately or if they lose control. And for some it’s because it’s just the right thing to do - like the Americans who flew in from California.

The same motives can drive people to fulfil your gods’ requests.

A knight may go slay a rampaging dragon because he’s responsible for defending his realm, nevermind that it’s really the latest spat between a couple of gods he doesn’t know or care about.

A smith’s daughter may journey deep into foreign lands to smash the staff of the sea god because the tsunami it would cause would destroy her home town.

A band of vagabonds might undertake to battle the evil Cult of Novel and Hurtful Slurs simply because it ought to be done.

The perilous mission to the firey caldera of Mount Doom to throw in a couple of tim tams and a cuppa may have trouble finding volunteers

Comment: Loved it!
Sometimes you are the closest mortal at hand, and legends don't write themselves.

Answer (score 3):

> What can be the incentive for them? Many of those adventurers do not worship the gods nor do they fear the gods.

Imagine that many *ordinary people* believe in the Gods, even if experienced adventurers are more cynical. So it is a good idea for the upper classes to at least pretend that they believe as well. Usually not to the point of going on suicidal quests themselves, but certainly enough to cheer those who go on.

*"<strike>Slay the dragon</strike> perform the quest and win the hand of the princess and half the kingdom. Or the eternal gratitude of the crown, at the very least."*

Add an upper class/noble culture where the oldest son inherits the title and the entire family fortune. The second son gets a small allowance, daughters get dowries. Yet infant mortality is so high that there must be *a heir and a spare.* So what do you do with those landless *second sons?* Some go into church service. Some become courtiers at the court of a brother or cousin. But those who want to become something in their own right, they have to take risks. Start a civil war. Support the pretender in a foreign civil war. Go on a quest.

Answer (score 1):

> The gods do not have obligation to intervene in the people business and they can restart genesis if everybody is gone, people are just a pawn to them but still there are men and women forming a line to sign up for the perilous vacation...

Take a page from The Order of the Stick. The Gods are trying to contain a universe-destroying entity, but they can't fight it themselves. Only mortals can. So the Gods send them mortals against the beast because the alternative for the mortals is to cease existing (not death - I mean literal nullification). Whenever mortals botch things up the Gods create another universe to try and fight the entity again.